# PyTorch Lightning - Runtime Error: Different Every Time

Tags: pytorch-lightning

On my 2nd epoch of training, I hit a surprise error:

```
  File "/home/rschaef/CoCoLab-Pretrained-Representation-Distillation/prd_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/optimizer_loop.py", line 151, in closure
    self._zero_grad_fn()
  File "/home/rschaef/CoCoLab-Pretrained-Representation-Distillation/prd_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/optimizer_loop.py", line 313, in zero_grad_fn
    self._optimizer_zero_grad(batch_idx, optimizer, opt_idx)
  File "/home/rschaef/CoCoLab-Pretrained-Representation-Distillation/prd_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/optimizer_loop.py", line 409, in _optimizer_zero_grad
    self.trainer.accelerator.optimizer_zero_grad(self.trainer.current_epoch, batch_idx, optimizer, opt_idx)
  File "/home/rschaef/CoCoLab-Pretrained-Representation-Distillation/prd_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/accelerators/accelerator.py", line 341, in optimizer_zero_grad
    model_ref.optimizer_zero_grad(current_epoch, batch_idx, optimizer, opt_idx)
  File "/home/rschaef/CoCoLab-Pretrained-Representation-Distillation/prd_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/core/lightning.py", line 1675, in optimizer_zero_grad
    optimizer.zero_grad()
  File "/home/rschaef/CoCoLab-Pretrained-Representation-Distillation/prd_venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/optim/optimizer.py", line 214, in zero_grad
    p.grad.detach_()
RuntimeError: Can't detach views in-place. Use detach() instead. If you are using DistributedDataParallel (DDP) for training, and gradient_as_bucket_view is set as True, gradients are views of DDP buckets, and hence detach_() cannot be called on these gradients. To fix this error, please refer to the Optimizer.zero_grad() function in torch/optim/optimizer.py as the solution.
python-BaseException
```

I'm not training with `ddp`. This is my trainer:

```
    trainer = pl.Trainer(
        default_root_dir=run_path_str,
        # gpus=4,
        # strategy='ddp',
        logger=wandb_logger,
        callbacks=callbacks,
        max_epochs=25,
        log_every_n_steps=25,
        check_val_every_n_epoch=5,
        # fast_dev_run=True,
        # overfit_batches=10,
        # limit_train_batches=10,
    )
```

What is causing this error to appear on Epoch 2?

Edit 1: The error isn't consistent. On the next run attempt, I get `AttributeError: 'weakref' object has no attribute 'grad_fn'`

Edit 2: The next run raised `RuntimeError: cannot call get_autograd_meta() on undefined tensor`.

What the hell is going on?

Edit 3: Now I'm hitting `AttributeError: 'FrameSummary' object has no attribute 'grad_fn'`

Comment: I'm getting similar errors! [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/PyTorchLightning/pytorch-lightning/issues/11067) is probably relevant. Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @JackKelly I'm the same person as the person who posted that GitHub issue. I'll investigate more closely today. My memory is hazy and I might have had a different problem